# I created an RSA key, but can't see the files in my home folder

Tags: ssh

I literally just installed Ubuntu onto a VM for the first time today. I created an RSA key using {ssh-keygen -t rsa} and can verify the files exist by way of {ls -l ~/.ssh}. When I go to my home folder the id_rsa.pub and id_rsa files are not there.... there is no ssh folder. In a file under computer/etc, there is an ssh folder, but it contains two files called moduli and ssh_config. What am I doing wrong? I'm supposed to send the .pub file to our server administrator for a class and don't know where it is. Please help this newbie.

Comment: If you're looking for hidden files ("dotfiles") in the file browser, you will need to select 'Show hidden files' from the menu (or by using the shortcut Ctrl+H)

Comment: Oh my gosh, it took me a minute of hovering around and clicking on different settings and properties, but I found the 'Show hidden files,' and there are my files. I know this is way silly for probably anybody on here, but I have been racking my brain and PC for a couple of hours on this. Eternal thanks...

Comment: Didn't it prompt for an output folder? Also, which version you are using?

Comment: I mentioned it was supposed to be in my home folder, and so it was. It was just a hidden file and I didn't know to look for, nor where to find how to select that preference. @steeldriver got me straightened out, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You got a message like this:

> Your identification has been saved in /home/b/.ssh/id_rsa.
>   Your public key has been saved in /home/b/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

Open your home folder and press `Ctrl + H` and you'll see folder .ssh